# How to check for permissions for sched_setscheduler()?

Tags: c++, linux, permissions, scheduler, vps

I have a C++ application that calls `sched_setscheduler(pid, SCHED_RR, ... )`.

The application runs on Linux with root permissions. and the call usually works. Only in one particular virtual private server it fails with `EPERM`.

Has anybody seen a situation where a process with root privledges can't do this ?

How do I check if the process has all the necessary permissions to avoid the call otherwise ?

**Update:**
I found out its only virtual servers based on Virtuozzo where this happens. Virtual machines using eg. KVM are OK.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure exactly which kernel you are running but this problem is discussed [here](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.linux.kernel/1085531).  The fix for it is [here](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/tip/tip.git/commit/?id=f44937718ce3b8360f72f6c68c9481712517a867).  The problem is with `CONFIG_SCHED_AUTOGROUP`; it doesn't support `SCHED_RR` or `SCHED_FIFO`.  However, if you're like me, this may still not solve your problem. The issue is with this code (this 3.4.47 code contains the above patch) in `kernel/sched/core.c` (`kernel/sched.c` in earlier kernels):

```
/*
 * Do not allow realtime tasks into groups that have no runtime
 * assigned.
 */
if (rt_bandwidth_enabled() && rt_policy(policy) &&
        task_group(p)->rt_bandwidth.rt_runtime == 0 &&
        !task_group_is_autogroup(task_group(p))) {
    task_rq_unlock(rq, p, &flags);
    return -EPERM;
}
```

In my case, one system works and one system doesn't work, predicated on the `!task_group_is_autogroup(task_group(p))` clause (both systems are running the exact same kernel).  In the failing system this clause evaluates to 1 (i.e. it's not in the autogroup).  The patch appears in as early as the 3.1.10 kernel.  It sounds like you have the same problem I have, since only one of your systems is failing.  This points to a configuration issue.  I did not find that the `/proc/sys/kernel/sched_autogroup_enabled` solved the problem; I ran into the above problem with autogroups enabled, and another problem (`rt_runtime` was zero on one system, 950000000 on the other) when I disabled it, even though `/sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct/cpu.rt_runtime_us` (which I believe is a direct link, or at least is related, to `rt_runtime`) said 950000000 in both cases.

So it *looks* like one task is assigned to the autogroup and succeeds, and one task is not and fails because it has no runtime.

**UPDATE:**

I did find a workaround sort of solution that I discuss in https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/115114/why-are-cgroups-mapped-differently-on-these-two-systems-by-systemd.  If I change the cgroup mapping of the process so it is in the root cgroup, it solves the problem.  This can be permanently changed by setting `DefaultController` to null in `/etc/systemd/system.conf`.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to change the priority of the application itself or of another process in the system?

The man page `man 2 sched_setscheduler` says in the section *Privileges and resource limits* that only processes that own the capability **CAP_SYS_NICE** can change the scheduling policy to realtime. At least in kernels before 2.6.12 and it gets more complicated in newer kernels.

Maybe the machine that gives you trouble has got some special configuration regarding capabilities or something.

I think to detect this situation you can simply continue doing what you already do: call sched_setscheduler and if it returns EPERM, well, no permission.

Comment: This is happening on a kernel newer than 2.6.12. But how would I check for CAP_SYS_NICE anyway ? The call to sched_setscheduler() actually happends deep in a library so I want to check wether to call the lib or skip it.

Comment: There are userspace programs like `captest` or `setcap` that deal with capabilities. And the `capget` and `capset` system calls (see `man 2 capget`). Regarding your check: As a last resort you can still try a sched_setscheduler before entering your library but that might flip your priorities around for a moment... I suggest you consult the named manual pages for sched_setscheduler and the capabilities and try to deduce what is the cause of the EPERM.

Comment: If you really want to get to the bottom of this you may even need to look into the Linux kernel sources of the kernel version in question that implement the sched_setscheduler call to see on what conditions EPERM is returned.